# How to open a page only, if someone write the right password/username

Tags: php, html, forms, authentication

I am working on a simple login form with sessions..Here is my index.php code

```
     <?php
   ob_start();
 session_start();
 ?>
 <?
   // error_reporting(E_ALL);
   // ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 ?>
 <html lang = "en">
   <head>  </head>
<body>    
  <h2>Enter Username and Password</h2> 
  <div class = "container form-signin">
     <?php 
     $msg = '';
     if (isset($_POST['login']) && !empty($_POST['username']) && !empty($_POST['password']))
     {
     if ($_POST['username'] == '1' && $_POST['password'] == '1'  )
     {
     $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
     $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
     header('Location: /test/login.php');
     }
     else $msg = 'not working';
     }
     ?>

  </div> <!-- /container -->

  </div> 

  <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);?>" method="post" >
  <?php echo $msg; ?>
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input  type="password" name="password"  >
  <input type="submit" name="login">
  </form>


  </body>
 </html>
```

When someone write the right password, he will go to this page
localhost:8080/test/login.php 
but, if someone try to open "localhost:8080/test/login.php" directly, he will go to this page "localhost:8080/test/index.php".

this is my login.php code

```
 <?php
session_start();
  if ($_POST['username'] == '1' && $_POST['password'] == '1'  )
  {
     $_SESSION['valid'] = true;
     $_SESSION['timeout'] = time();
     header('Location: /test/login.php');
     }
 else{
header('Location: /test/index.php/');
   }
  ?>


 test 1
```

Comment: you are sending headers after writing html - you would need to use output buffering to allow that. Betteroption is to have the PHP before any html content

Comment: I mean, the login.php is not working... :(

Comment: You never check if the session is set...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Youve made several small mistakes (see comments), but the big mistake you make is that the session is never checked. Use this at login.php :

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION["valid"])){
header("location: index.php");
die();
}
?>
```

This checks if the session is set, and if not redirects back to index php